# Geddy JS overwrites custom id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geddy

I am running an app with Geddy JS (v 0.6.18) with a Mongo DB - Before saving models I am setting a custom id property. Nevertheless, Geddy JS (or Mongo DB?) seems to overwrite this custom id property with a String looking like:

EAF9AAD8-3A5D-462B-8733-376AB17ECBEC

Instead of my custom 10-length string.

This behaviuor did not occur before updating to the lastest version. Can anyone explain me, what's happending here and how I am able to turn this off?

Comment: I have not reproduced, but can you check the value of the autoincrement flag in your model? Or just set it to false and see if it works.

Comment: this is definitely not MongoDB that's doing this - it must be one of the layers above it.

Comment: @MiguelMadero I haven't explicitly set it. Have to check.

Comment: Should it be in Geddy's model? Couldn't find anything there.

Comment: I'm also interested in this...Miguel, any thoughts?

Comment: I have to specify that I don't use MongoDB... I'm just using the in-memory option

Comment: @Felix, which version were you using before where this was working? I looked at the code and it seems like we have always been overwritting the id (not saying this is right). I also checked the objectid in the mongodb_wrapper and they check if it's not null before generating the id, so this is definately something to do with the model layer in geddy. Could you let me know the previous version number?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru it looks like the in-memory adapter works this way. I'll have a look, both should let you override or change the type.

Comment: @MiguelMadero Before it was 0.4 something...it wasn't working on 0.6 something...I just updated to 0.7.7. It seems to have fixed the bug!?

Comment: I still have my id overwritten...if I have my own id property in the model, isn't this the way to save it? -> `id: params.id`

Comment: I've forgot to tell that my input has the name `id`...so params.id should extract the value from the field, I guess

Comment: @Felix cool (but odd since it seems to have the same issue, I added a few tests for this case to make sure all the adapters behave the same)

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru yes it should. You could test that separately, but even if you manually set in the controller myobject.id = "something" right before save it gets overwritten by the memoryAdapter .

Comment: yeah...it overwrites everything I try